# Keeping button disabled through screen rotation (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-savedstate

I'm working on making a **tic-tac-toe game** with android studio and ran into a problem I can't seem to figure out regarding `onSaveInstanceState`.

I made the bored a **3x3** **2d** array of buttons and on each click I do `b.setEnable(false)`.

This works well except when I rotate the screen the buttons become enabled again. I'm not sure whats the best (or even a way) to go about saving this state.

**2d arrays** aren't allowed to be passed through `onSaveInstanceState`.

I'm not sure if anyone needs to see my code but I can post if need be. basically is there a way to save every attribute of a widget you changed through code, or even just one specific attribute through a screen rotation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow... Please add your codes to the question, it will help others to address the problem much easier and faster

Comment: you should use viewmodels.  What this means is that all of your code that has any data processing or reading AT ALL in it should be in a separate class.  the only thing you should have to do when you rotate the display is... redraw the display.